# Python subprocess on Flask server -- how to detect when subprocess terminates?

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I am building an app in React Native which generates 3D model files based on user input as part of its functionality. The app takes a 'code' from the user on its main screen and sends it to a Flask server using a POST request, which then generates the model file using the code at a fixed URI (e.g. /static/mod.obj). Then, the app transitions to a separate display screen and GETs the model files at that URI to display. Currently, the Flask server generates the model files for each POST request in a separate subprocess, as below:

```python
@app.route('/genpdb', methods=['POST'])
def genpdb():
    # ...
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'convPDB.py', '--code', json["code"]]) # python script convPDB.py generates 3D model from 'code' param in request JSON
    return json['code'] # response doesn't return anything important; generated model is simply hosted at a fixed uri e.g. /static/mod.obj
```

I used the Popen constructor to create the subprocesses so that they would be non-blocking. However, I would like some way for the client to be notified when the generation script has finished (i.e. when the subprocess terminates) so that the app doesn't switch to the display screen before the model files are actually there. Is there some way for a unique subprocess spawned by the server to notify the client which requested it that it has terminated?

Comment: There is a .wait() module you can try, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait

Comment: Your process could write to a different directory and move it to the static folder when done. Now your browser code can do refreshes or something to wait til its there.